# Rails Wisper skip listener callback

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec-rails, wisper

I use Rails Wisper gem and I want to execute listener callback (which sends email) only during specific tests (where I test email sending). In other tests I don't want to send emails even if in production my callback would send them.

Is it possible with Wisper?

**publisher** (app/models/order.rb)

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Wisper::Publisher

  after_save do
    publish(:order_after_save, self)
  end

end
```

**listener/observer** (app/observers/mailer_order_observer.rb)

```
class MailerOrderObserver

  def order_after_save order
    if order.status_id_changed? && order.status.notify?
      # send email
    end
  end
end
```

**subscription** (config/initializers/wisper.rb)

```
Rails.application.config.to_prepare do
  Wisper.clear if Rails.env.development? || Rails.env.test?
  # add observers
  Wisper.subscribe(MailerOrderObserver.new)
end
```

**test** (spec/observers/mailer_order_observer_spec.rb)

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe MailerOrderObserver, type: :model do
  let (:order) { create(:order, :with_items) }

  it 'should send email' do
    order.status = create(:status_released)
    # emails are handled by external service, line below just triggers
    # sending
    expect(order.save).to eq(true)
  end
end
```

I the test above I want to execute `MailerOrderObserver` `order_after_save` callback, but not in any other tests (many "orders" are created and changed what normally would trigger email sending).

I use RSpec as testing framework and FactoryGirl.

Of course creating new `Order` instances with FactoryGirl triggers mailing, which is also not desired.

Comment: show how do you test

Comment: You would be better off subscribing the listener to an instance of a publisher (e.g. `order.subscribe(MailerOrderObserver.new)`) instead of globally (i.e. `Wisper.subscribe(MailerOrderObserver.new)`). Otherwise you are just getting in to the same problems as regular ActiveRecord callbacks (they can't be turned off).

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution (any better answer will be appreciated):

1. Unsubscribe listener in question in RSpec `config.before(:suite)` block 
   so it won't receive any notifications during the tests.

**spec/spec_helper.rb**

```
RSpec.configure do |config|

  config.before(:suite) do
    # unsubscribe observer
    Rails.application.config.to_prepare do
      Wisper.unsubscribe(MailerOrderObserver.new)
    end
  end
end
```

2. Subscribe listener only for selected tests.

**spec/observers/mailer_order_observer_spec.rb**

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe MailerOrderObserver, type: :model do
  # ! prevents lazy loading
  let! (:order) { create(:order, :with_items) }

  describe '.order_after_save' do
    before do
      Wisper.subscribe(MailerOrderObserver.new)
    end

    it 'should send email' do
      order.status = create(:status_released)
      expect(order.save).to eq(true)
    end
  end
end
```

This way `MailerOrderObserver` receives notifications from publisher only when `Wisper.subscribe...` is executed before the test.

Note that it is convenient to use `let!` (with exclamation mark) in order to instantiate `order` before subscribing to the Wisper. This way only one publisher notification is received during test. Using `let` instead will cause two notifications: one after `create...` and one caused by `order.save`.